# Is it good idea to use Handler for UI changes in Android

Tags: android

For example, I have a situation where rewind indicator must be displayed when the user presses a certain key. 
I detect keypress in onKey listener, check the keycode and if it's the rewind key I call the function `showRewind()`

```
 public static void showRewind(){
        (new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rewindText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Notice the handler and Looper.getMainLooper() I use here, if I don't do that, the UI doesn't get updated instantly. That's the only solution I could find to instantly update it on key press and it works perfectly, but somehow I have the feeling I'm not doing something right.

I'm fairly new to Android and I had to learn it very quickly, so I couldn't get deep into the documentations and use practical solutions from stackoverflow in general.

Now my question: is what I'm doing here (using handler with main looper to update UI) generally a good idea, or is there a better solution to instantly update UI on keypress?

Comment: Did you try `runOnUiThread`? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: Okay it works just as well, I guess it's better to use?

Comment: Just may be simplier

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating main or UI thread (treat it as critical section in the multi-threaded environment), it should be done in a consistent and synchronized way. In order to do that, there is this mechanism of message queue for the main or UI thread and associated handler for the same. The looper will loop through the message queue to get it executed. So the best way to update the main or UI thread is through handler and will be the basic mechanism. Even if there will be utility classes doing things for you to update the main or UI thread, they in turn will rely on this handler mechanism.
From my point of view, this is the best way to update the main or UI thread.